# How do you set a full page background color in Tailwind css?

Tags: tailwind-css

How do you set the full page background in Tailwind?

The only attribute I can see to use is `h-screen`, but that doesn't work when I resize the browser.

[image]

Here's my code:

```html
<body class="h-screen bg-gradient-to-b from-gray-100 to-gray-300">
```

---

Full html example:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>lkjh</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>

    <body class="h-screen bg-gradient-to-b from-gray-100 to-gray-300">
        <br />a<br />a<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />a<br /><br /><br /><br />a<br /><br /><br />a<br /><br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />
    </body>
</html>
```

css file

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

`"tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2"`

Comment: It's working for my codebase on the latest tailwind version. Can you please share the skeleton code.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Change `h-screen` to `min-h-screen`

Comment: this worked for me, looking at docs, still not sure why only h-screen left my bottom screen unfullfilled

Answer (score 8):

#### Short answer

change `h-screen` to `min-h-screen`.

---

#### But why?

> `h-screen` :takes height of the viewport.

##### What happens when scrolled ?

```
 Now the `total height` is `viewport height + scrolled height`
                                                  
                               h-screen           extra height
```

So it doesn't expand itself to have height of the entire screen during scroll, So this can be overcomed by using `min-h-screen`, meaning minimum should be the viewport height and in the occurance of scroll , expand yourself to have maximum possible height.